# How to use the envir argument in knit_child?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm writing an R package in which I have such a Rmd template:

**child.Rmd:**

````
```{r}
print(x)
```
````

and such a function:

```
child <- function(){
  myenv <- new.env()
  assign("x", 0, envir=myenv)
  # knit: 
  output <- knit_child("child.Rmd", envir=myenv)
  return(output)
}
```

Then I knit such a file :

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(mypackage)
```

`r child()`
````

But that doesn't work, the output is:

```
print(x)
## Error: object 'x' not found
```

Below is a self-contained example, without involving any package, I don't know whether this is really equivalent and what I really need is the package structure:

````
```{r}
child <- function(){
  myenv <- new.env()
  assign("x", 0, envir=myenv)
  # knit: 
  output <- knit_child("child.Rmd", envir=myenv)
  return(output)
}
```

`r child()`
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#knitr) of **knitr** (>= v1.6.3): `knit_child()` has gained a new argument `envir`, and you can pass an arbitrary environment to it.

Answer (score 1):

`knit_child` does not seem to pass `envir` to `knit`. I don't really know why.

One thing you can do is to move `myenv` outside the function so that it is available to the child.

````
```{r}
myenv <- new.env()
child <- function(){
  assign("x", 0, envir=myenv)
  # knit: 
  output <- knit_child("child.Rmd")
  return(output)
}
```

`r child()`
````

**child.Rmd**

````
```{r}
print(get('x', envir=myenv))
```
````

Comment: Not a bad idea, thanks. I'm still wondering why `knit_child` seems to ignore the `envir` argument (@Yihui could help ?)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You are right that `knit_child()` used to ignore `envir`. I just fixed it.